# Wiring a combination switch/GFCI outlet with lightswitch downstream

Tags: electrical

I need some help wiring a combination switch/GFCI outlet in the following situation.  The second diagram is from the instructions and seems to match my situation, however they have an outlet downstream rather than a lightswitch (is this irrelevant?) and there are 2 black cables coming from downstream which seems to be a mistake that I need clarified.

[image]
[image]

The existing wiring is a big mess:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Looking into the back of the box:

[image]

An illustration of the current wiring:

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Do you have the installation directions for your GFCI? Does it address this situation?

Comment: Hi Daniel.  It comes with 3 diagrams and the 3rd one seems similar to my situation, however they have another outlet downstream rather than a lightswitch, and more importantly, they seem to have made a mistake and forgot to colour-code the wires properly, as there are 2 black wires coming from downstream rather than a black and a white.

Comment: That diagram does not make sense to me. It seems to show wires labeled "black switch lead" (which would normally be a switched hot) connected to the terminal for the load-side grounded conductors (neutral).

Comment: @JimmyFix-it -- that's where the wires for the switch come out

Comment: The two black switch leads internally connect only to the switch, it's like a completely separate device from the GFCI.

Comment: The switch currently controls power to the outlet as well as the lightbulb.  Power is constant to the lightswitch.  The reason I started looking at it was to give constant power to the outlet.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I see, so the diagram shows the switch (as a stand-alone device) receiving power from the load side of the GFI, the other is the switched hot to the light fixture, 10-4. This makes sense, if the switch were powered by the device internally, it might prevent one from segregating circuits.

Comment: @MarcGuay -- do you know where the bundle of bare wires is connected to?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Same place as the white cables (improperly located ground cables it seems).  And they've actually broken off and are not connected properly anymore.  You can see that in this photo: https://c4.staticflickr.com/8/7533/27467130003_a71ac0291d_b.jpg.   In case it isn't clear, I am not trying to replicate the current wiring setup, but rather create the one in my first diagram of the original post.

Comment: @MarcGuay -- one last thing -- are there bare ground wires in the back of the box?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No.

Comment: Do you want to GFCI protect the lights?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, unless there's a reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the diagram so far, here's how the GFCI switch/outlet combo should be wired:

- Black from breaker to LINE HOT on GFCI/switch
- White from breaker to LINE WHITE on GFCI/switch
- White from switch-cable and white from light nutted together and pigtailed to LOAD WHITE on GFCI/switch
- Black from switch-cable and one black from GFCI/switch nutted together and pigtailed to LOAD HOT on GFCI/switch
- Other black from GFCI/switch nutted to black from light

(If your GFCI has the two-wire, clamp-plate terminals as in the diagram depicted, you can save a couple nuts and the pigtail wires by terminating both wires to the clamp plate instead -- they are designed to terminate two wires, one in each hole.)

Comment: I've modified the diagram that came with the device to match your description - does this seem correct?  https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8581/27734194033_a8e6c24d31_b.jpg

Comment: @MarcGuay -- yup, that's it

Comment: Thank you.  Does their colour labelling make sense to you?

Comment: And is it correct that the light/switched load will not be grounded?

Comment: @MarcGuay -- it seems like whoever drew their diagram goofed, and yes, in your case, it is correct that things aren't going to be grounded -- the GFCI protection is an acceptable substitute.